# The locality of Wess-Zumino terms

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking, quantum-anomalies, 1pi-effective-action

Suppose the simple theory with chiral fermions possessing non-trivial gauge anomalies cancellation:
$$
S = \int d^4 x \big(\bar{\psi}i\gamma_{\mu}D^{\mu}_{\psi}\psi + \bar{\kappa}i\gamma_{\mu}D^{\mu}_{\kappa}\kappa\big),
$$
where
$$
D^{\mu}_{\psi} = \partial^{\mu} - iA^{\mu}_{L}P_{L} -iA^{\mu}_{R}P_{R}, \quad D^{\mu}_{\kappa} = \partial^{\mu}+iA^{\mu}_{L}P_{L} +iA^{\mu}_{R}P_{R} 
$$
Although separately $\psi, \kappa$ sectors are anomalous, together their gauge anomalies are cancelled:
$$
\partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}_{L/R,\psi, \kappa} = \pm \frac{1}{96\pi^2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}F_{\mu\nu}^{L/R}F_{\alpha\beta}^{L/R}, \quad \partial_{\mu}(J^{\mu}_{L/R,\psi}-J^{\mu}_{L/R,\kappa}) = 0
$$
Lets generate the mass for $\kappa$ fermion (by using spontaneous symmetry breaking with higgs singlet $fe^{i\varphi}$ with infinite mass for $f$) and integrate it out  in the limit $m_{\kappa}\to \infty$. Corresponding effective field theory has to be free from anomalies, so there must be (possibly non-local) term $\Gamma[A_{L}, A_{R},\varphi ]$ which reproduces the anomalous structure of $\kappa$ sector; I can call it the **Wess-Zumino term**. It is possible to write its explicit form, and it turns out that this form is **local** (a polynomial in $A, \varphi$ and their derivatives)!

However, as I know, the anomaly is the local expression given by the variation of the non-local action. So where the non-locality is hidden?

Comment: Your question looks too broad and open-ended to have a cogent answer here. Your basic conceit about the interchangeability of chiral fermions with WZW effective terms is standard practice in the industry. We demonstrate chiral delocalization and the bulk-boundary interplay in our 
[Hill & Zachos AnnPhys 323 (2008) 3065](http://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/36340327/AnnPhys08.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ56TQJRTWSMTNPEA&Expires=1481815997&Signature=8R1EuzJeNFMKTFK1lrfExWBWziA%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DChern_Simons_and_WZW_anomaly_cancelation.pdf).

Comment: ...and also 
[Hill & Zachos PhysRev D71 (2005) 046002](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283502989_PhysRevD71046002_Dimensional_deconstruction_and_Wess-Zumino-Witten_terms).

Comment: Above Ann Phys Link that [works](https://www.academia.edu/10251563/Chern_Simons_and_WZW_anomaly_cancelations_across_dimensions).

Comment: @CosmasZachos : so, You mean that above model with anomalies cancellation by generating the local term can be thought as the 5-d model, in which the anomaly cancellation is, of course, non-local?

Comment: You might see it that way... An interplay of the boundary and the bulk....  Anything topological always has a whiff of higher dimensions, by dint of the generalized Stokes' theorem... Strict separation of locality and non locality may be subjective, unless precisely defined...